# How to enable acl in consul?

Tags: consul

I am trying to integrate Vault with consul and following this [url](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/consul/index.html) but its failing with the following error

> Failed to create new token: Unexpected response code: 401 (ACL support
>   disabled)

I am trying to run this command

```
CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN=242323-43434-6809-387b-a88a25bd3d9b ./consul acl token create -policy-name=global-management
```

What is the way to enable ACL in consul?

config.json file have following details

```
"primary_datacenter": "dc1",
  "acl": {
    "enabled": true,
    "default_policy": "deny",
    "down_policy": "extend-cache"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that i used either

```
# systemctl reload consul
```

or

```
# kill -SIGHUP $(pgrep consul)
```

in both cases consul dont apply(dont know why) new config settings.

you need RESTART consul  , that is

```
# systemctl restart consul
```

you can check if acl enabled via:

```
# consul info | grep -i acl
    acl = enabled
```

Answer (score -1):

`config.json` looks OK, but you will have to boostrap Consul ACL system first. This is described in the guide on how to setup Consul ACL system: https://learn.hashicorp.com/consul/security-networking/production-acls#create-the-initial-bootstrap-token

Comment: The learn guide documents how to bootstrap the ACL, but assumes it is already enabled. It does not say how to enable it.